# IF clausole inside WHERE match single value or any

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to add a clausole to `WHERE` in `mysql`, I need to match a single value if a condition is respected othewise any value is allowed (possibilities 0 or 1), but I don't know to achive this...in a "speaking" way:

```
WEHRE a.enabled=(CASE WHEN (a.operator_id=".$_SESSION['id'].") THEN 1 ELSE 0,1 END)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You lack a `WHEN`:

```
WHERE a.enabled=(CASE WHEN (a.operator_id=".$_SESSION['id'].") THEN 1 
                      ELSE a.enabled 
                 END
                )
```

Comment: Thank you! I missed it while writing the question, the need parted was the `a.enabled`

Answer (score 0):

```
WHERE a.enabled=
CASE 
WHEN a.operator_id=".$_SESSION['id']." THEN ".$_SESSION['id']." -- when condition is met, match enabled to session id
ELSE a.enabled -- else proceed anyway
END
```